# Show that $\{y:I\longrightarrow Y \mid y(j)=y(i) \;\; \forall j\in I\}$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology

Let $I$ be a non-empty set and $Y$ be a Hausdorff space. Fix $i\in I$ and define $$D:=\{y:I\longrightarrow Y \mid y(j)=y(i) \;\; \forall j\in I\}.$$

Show that $D$ is a closed subset of $Y^I:=\{f:I\longrightarrow Y\}$ when endowed with product topology.

Hope you can help. Thank you!

Comment: So $D$ is the collection of constant functions.  Makes $D$ look very like $Y$.

Comment: I think when you are talking about product topology you must give a topology on $I$, too. Is it discrete?

Comment: @Hamid the topology doesn't matter as we're taking the product over elements in $I$ so $Y^I=\prod_{i\in I}Y$ where the topology is given as the product topology.

Comment: so how will i show that $D$ is closed with respect to product topology? thank you

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f\in Y^I$ and $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in M}$ ($M$ is a directed set) be a net in $D$ with $f_\alpha\to f$ in product topology.

Let there exists some $j\neq i$ such that $f(i)\neq f(j)$. So there exist two open subsets of $Y$ like $U,V$   such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$ and $f(i)\in U, f(j)\in V$.

There exists an $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in M$ such that for all $\alpha\geq\alpha_1, \beta\geq\alpha_2$ $f_\alpha(i)\in U$ and $f_\alpha(j)\in V$ (Because $f_\alpha\to f$ in product topology and consequently $f_\alpha(i)\to f(i)$ in subspace topology and the same is true for all $j\in I$).

Let  $\alpha_0\in M$ with $\alpha_0\geq\alpha_1,\alpha_0\geq\alpha_2$ (we can suppose it because $M$ is directed).

Then for all $\alpha\geq\alpha_0, f_\alpha(i)\in U, f_\alpha(j)\in V$. But we know $f_\alpha(i)=f_\alpha(j)$ and so for any $\alpha\ge\alpha_0, f_\alpha(i)\in U\cap V$ which is contradiction.

Hence $f(i)=f(j)$ for all $j\in I$ which means $f\in D$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $\Delta=\{(y,y)\colon y\in Y\}\subset Y\times Y$. It is an easy exercise that $\Delta$ is closed if and only if $Y$ is hausdorff.

Also set $p_j\colon Y^I\to Y$, $p_j(f)=f(j)$. The maps $p_j$ are continuous.

Now 
$$D=\bigcap_{j\in I}(p_j,p_i)^{-1}[\Delta]$$
is an intersection of closed sets and hence closed.

Comment: I like this answer (although most of the detail is swept into the fact that $\Delta$ is closed).

Comment: The advantage is that one has to prove this only once. After that one can look at the definition and see: Everything continuos, ok; “for all”, ok; equality and space hausdorff, ok. Of course you are aware of that.

Comment: Yeah I agree, the thing I like is that as long as you have the previous result, you can use it directly instead of modifying the proof as I've done in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_{(j)}$ denote the $j$th factor of the product space $Y^{I}$ for $j\in I$ and let $p_j\colon Y^{I}\to Y_{(j)}$ be the usual projection onto the $j$th factor which is continuous by definition of the product topology.

Consider the complement $C=Y^I\setminus D$. We will show that $C$ is open. Let $y$ be an element in $C$ then there exist $j,j'$ such that $y(j)\neq y(j')$ and so as $Y$ is Hausdorff, there exist $U, U'$ such that $y(j)\in U$, $y(j')\in U'$ and $U\cap U'=\emptyset$.

Note that $p_j^{-1}(U)$ is open and $p_{j'}^{-1}(V)$ is open it follows that $C_y=p_j^{-1}(U)\cap p_{j'}^{-1}(V)$ is open, and because $U\cap V=\emptyset$ it follows that $C_y\cap D=\emptyset$. So, $C_y$ is an open subset of $C$ containing $y$. The union of arbitrarily many open sets is open and so $\bigcup_{y\in Y}C_y$ is open, but we see that $\bigcup_{y\in Y}C_y$ contains $y$ for each $y\in Y$ and each component of the union has empty intersection with $D$. It follows that $\bigcup_{y\in Y}C_y=C$ and so $C$ is an open subset of $Y^{I}$, hence $D$ is closed.